# I get the following error when I run npm start , the term npm is not recognized

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm run start
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: what is the node.js installation procedure you followed ?

Answer (score 0):

Update Path
Open the environmental variable and check the value of the path Variable as "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" or "C:\Program Files\nodejs". Add the new path, Then, close the Editor and restart it. This should resolve the issue.